# Find all instances of "Replace" but not ".Replace"

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Due to the unfortunate choice of method naming, this is proving nearly impossible to find an answer to this using SO/Google searches...

**TL;DR** How can I find all instances of the function `Replace(` in my application, but not the extension method `.Replace(`?

**Long version:** I am converting a large VB.Net app to C#.  Within the 250,000 lines of code I know there are usages of the Visual Basic [`Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5(v=vs.90).aspx) function, in addition to the [`String.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Is it possible to search for `Replace`, without including occurrences of `.Replace`?  I tagged RegEx as I was hoping that is the way, and had a [play about at RegExr](http://regexr.com/3ejs8), but can't figure it out fully.

Thanks.

Comment: Do not use Regexr, use RegexStorm.net. The regex you can use  is `(?<!\S)Replace\(`. Or `(?<!\.)Replace\(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I find all instances of the function `Replace(` in my application, but not the extension method `.Replace(`?

You need to use a regex with a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\.)Replace\(
^^^^^^^
```

The `(?<!\.)` lookbehind will invalidate all matches of `Replace(` that are immediately preceded with a `.`.

If you want to match `Replace(` that are only preceded with whitespace, use `(?<!\S)Replace\(`, the `(?<!\S)` will require either a whitespace or start of string before `Replace(`.

Since the `(` and `.` are special regex metacharacters, they must be escaped with `\`.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5C.%29Replace%5C%28&i=Replace%28s%2C%20%222%22%2C%221%22%29%20%0D%0As.Replace%28s%2C%20%222%22%2C%221%22%29%20Replace%28s%2C%20%222%22%2C%221%22%29%20).

Comment: Amazing, thanks.  How about if I had `Dim s = String.Concat(Replace("foo bar", "foo", ""), "bars")` (excuse weird example).  Would it still get found?

Comment: See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5c.%29Replace%5c%28&i=Dim+s+%3d+String.Concat%28Replace%28%22foo+bar%22%2c+%22foo%22%2c+%22%22%29%2c+%22bars%22%29). It will be found as there is no `.` in front.

Comment: Awesome.  I did update my test at RegExr but the results were different.  Is RegExr not very good or something?

Comment: As I said, do not use Regexr, it only supports ECMAScript 5 regex flavor. VS supports .NET regex flavor, it is different from JS.